# Possible to view Google Play Store notifications after they disappear?

Tags: google-play-store, notifications, google, ads

Due to excessive marketing ads and notifications, Google and other app developers have trained me to ignore ads and Android notifications.  I ***almost*** feel bad for companies that waste large amounts on money on their advertising budgets.

Recently (end of 2023 July, or beginning of 2023 August), however, Google suckered me into briefly noticing a promotion by disguising it as a possibly important notification within their Google Play Store.  Once I saw it was just a Google newsletter promoting a bunch of Android apps, I quickly dismissed it without looking at it further.

I wanted to go back and document which apps Google was promoting and how they were pushing them, but life got busy and I didn't have time to document it right away.  When I went back to the Google Play Store a couple weeks later, I could no longer see Google's notification or how to find this Google promotional newsletter.

**Is there a way to reveal previous notifications that have appeared in the Google Play Store's `Notifications` tab?**

(If not, does anyone happen to know the name of the Google promotional newsletter to which I refer and if it available within the Google Play Store or outside of it?)

Comment: @beeshyams perhaps worth noting that this doesn't appear as an Android notification, only as an internal "notification" inside the app.

Comment: That said, I don't think the promotional newsletters for the Play Store are shown elsewhere because they are personalized. My notifications are currently: New apps on Play (editors' monthly picks), Epic Seven now on PC, and Explore the regions of Genshin Impact. (I don't play any of them)

Comment: @AndrewT. I literally have just a few seconds to write at the moment... do you happen know where Google publishes "Editor's monthly picks"?  If not, I'll try to research it when I have a little time.  Thanks.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket based from the shared URL: https://play.google.com/store/apps/editorial?id=mc_apps_new_on_play_fcp

Comment: Now that I have explored it a bit more, looks like some of them are also shown as a banner on the web version of the Play Store. But still, not all of them are shown, and since there's no centralized page, it's hard to check.

Comment: @AndrewT. That link you provided is very helpful. Thank you. Besides places like the Wayback Machine (archive.org), do you have any idea how to see previous versions of their "New apps we love"?